# How to use Arguments in ProcessStartInfo()

Tags: c#, processstartinfo

I am trying to code the following to run a python script in c# :-

```
 ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 startinfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe";
 startinfo.Arguments = "-ssh username@lpl250srd01  -pw pass /home/abc/dComponents/bin/python eggs/beans/EGG-INFO/scripts/beanstalktop.py";
```

In the above there is a space between `"python eggs"` which means i need to execute the `.py` file but c# takes it as python directory and eggs as seperate directory and throws me an error.

Can any one help me in solving this??

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the arguments file path like:

```
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");
        info.Arguments = "\"c:\\temp\\test test\\test.txt\"";
        Process.Start(info);
```

Answer (score 0):

as simple as this :)

```
        Process process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                UseShellExecute = true,
                FileName = "pythonFile.py",
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                Arguments = "-sk server -sky exchange -pe -n CN=localhost -ir LocalMachine -is Root -ic MyCA.cer -sr LocalMachine -ss My MyAdHocTestCert.cer"
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        // this line waits till the python file is
        // finished and then resumes the code
        process.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

i use C#
u try

```
private void RunSqlPlusScript(string scriptFilePath, string connectionString)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "sqlplus";
            startInfo.Arguments = connectionString + " @" + scriptFilePath;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();

                Task<string> outputTask = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
                Task<string> errorTask = process.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();

                process.WaitForExit();

                string output = outputTask.Result;
                string error = errorTask.Result;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Output: " + output);
                    //LogToTextFile("Output: " + output + "\nRun script on sqlplus", false);
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + error);
                    LogToTextFile("Run script on sqlplus", "fail, " + "Error: " + error); 
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            LogToTextFile("Exception: " + ex.Message + "\nRun script on sqlplus", "fail");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**